Visual Studio Code search in method dropdown
I'm sure that at some point of time I could search for a function name within the dropdown list of functions/methods. When I try now with Ctrl+F I'm taken to the standard find within the file box.
Apparently I need to add more information because most of the post is images. I don't know what else to say though !
My version of VS Code is 1.92.2
Cheers
Mike


The suggested duplicate questions do not answer my question. I know how to find files in VS, I also know how to show/hide sections of code.
What I want to do is search in the object property dropdown list.
